# HasDbFunction not mapping the CLR function to the SQL Server function

Tags: c#, sql-server-2016, ef-core-5.0

I want to create MyDbFunction scalar function in SQL sever and call it from a .NET 5 application using the HasDbFunction mapping. For some reason the mapping is always ignored. I have simplified my example to make sure it's not a signature/arguments issue but that has not helped. I built it following the official documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/user-defined-function-mapping

Step 1.
I created this CLR function:

```
public int MyCLRFunction (int @Code)
  => throw new NotSupportedException("Mapping issue for MyDbFunction");
```

Step2.
I added the mapping to my datacontext SPContext as below:

```
static void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)  
{                 
  modelBuilder.HasDbFunction(typeof(SPContext).GetMethod(nameof(SPContext.MyCLRFunction), new[] 
  { typeof(int) })).HasName("MyDbFunction");
}
```

When I run it in debug mode, I can see the debugger calling the mapping when running OnModelCreating.
I expect that when calling MyCLRFunction(2) it would return 42 using after calling MyDbFunction on the database.
It shouldn't be triggering the exception in the body of the CLRFunction but exception is always triggered. What could cause the mapping to be ignored?

Code for the SQL Function on the default schema

```
Create FUNCTION [dbo].[MyDbFunction]
(
    @Code int
    
)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN

return 42

END
```

I tried to add this tag, but not helping either

```
[DbFunction("MyDbFunction", "dbo")]
public int MyCLRFunction (int @Code)
  => throw new NotSupportedException("Mapping issue for MyDbFunction");
```

I tried to define MyCLRFunction as a static method in another class as suggested in the official documentation:

```
In the example, the method is defined on DbContext, but it can also be defined as a static method inside other classes.
```

I am not sure how this is supposed to work because if it's defined as a static method in another class and run it without calling the datacontext first the mapping with HasDbFunction is never being called.

Comment: The mapping is only effective if the query is fed as a whole to the EF Core provider for translation; if a part transitions into LINQ to Objects the unmapped function will be called. Likewise if you call the function directly, without going through a DB context. That is to say, you can invoke the function even if it's in another class, but not outside a LINQ query on a model.

Comment: does that mean that if I want to run the scalar function idependantly I must call db.MyTable.Single(t=>db.MyCLRFunction(2)) and not db.MyCLRFunction(2)? Is there a more appropriate way of doing this?

Comment: @sofsntp It's sort of explained in [EF.Functions mapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/database-functions#effunctions-mapping) section of the documentation: *"Further, since the intention of these methods is to invoke a database function in the translated query, trying to evaluate them on the client results in an exception."*. With simple words, they are supposed to be used *only* as part of a LINQ to Entities queries.

Comment: what would be the most common way to call a scalar function that retrieves a decimal value from a set of parameters?

Comment: this call doesn't feel right: sp.MyTable.Where(t=>t.Code == X).Select(t=>sp.MyCLRFunction(2)).First();  with X being anything with a single record

Comment: In the (quite unlikely) case that you really want to retrieve nothing more than a scalar (not an entity) I'd say don't use EF at all and just execute a raw `SqlCommand` to call the function. You can use Dapper to make this a little more pleasing. Alternatively, you could of course create a view that just does a `SELECT dbo.MyFunction() AS X` and map an entity to it, which is clumsy for a single value but makes more sense if multiple values could be returned that way. In general there's little point to standalone scalar T-SQL functions.

Answer (score 0):

So far the most efficient I see is this:

```
    public static decimal? MyFunction(int code)
    {
        using (var db = new MyContext())
        {
            try
            {
                return db.AnyEntityWithValues.Take(1).Select(t => db.MyCLRFunction(code).Single();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

I wish I could just do without using an extension method of the DataContext

```
  var myVal = db.MyCLRFunction(code);
```

Comment: You could, if you supplied an implementation -- if `MyCLRFunction` belongs to `MyContext`, it can use `this.Database.Connection.ExecuteScalar<int>("SELECT dbo.MyDbFunction()")` (using Dapper). With more effort you can probably get the function name from the model somewhere without hard-coding it (and thus use the same implementation for all functions) but I couldn't write that off the top of my head.

Comment: seems this feature will come back eventually but not anytime soon https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/11624

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you, I solved it by using **GetRuntimeMethod** instead of **GetMethod**.

```
  modelBuilder.HasDbFunction(typeof(EFFunctions)
          .GetRuntimeMethod(
              nameof(EFFunctions.fn_GetString),
              new[] { typeof(DateTime), typeof(int), typeof(int), typeof(string), typeof(int)}
          ))
          .HasName(nameof(EFFunctions.fn_GetString));
```